# Is there a way to upload files to the theme directory

Tags: 7, forms

I use the following code to upload images should be used in slideshow of the theme settings `theme-settings.php`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
      $form['best_responsive_settings']['slideshow']['slideimages'][] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#title' => t('Image').' #'.$i,
        '#upload_location' => file_default_scheme() . '://theme/backgrounds/',
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('background_file'), 
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg')),

      );
  }
```

Those files are uploaded to: `sites\default\files\theme\backgrounds` I want to change the uploading location to `sites\all\themes\best_responsive\images\backgrounds`. **How could I change `'#upload_location'` to do that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like the file module places any restriction on the upload path, so in theory it should be as simple as:

```
'#upload_location' => DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/images/backgrounds';
```

However, having your theme folder writable by the web server would usually indicate that permissions are not set correctly. It would be a better idea to fix those, and save your images in the proper location (i.e. sites/default/files); see [Securing file permissions and ownership](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924) for full details.